# How to apply scipy.optimize.minimize on heston model calibrations

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, quantlib

I am looking to calibrate the Heston model daily using scipy.optimize.minimize() over a period of time.
Some basic background information; I have collected information on 250.000 option trades over almost 4 years (so approx. 150 trades a day) and am looking to calibrate the heston model daily using option information on that specific day. I am however, quite new to nonlinear optimalization and even more so to scipy.optimize.minimize().
So far I have defined three functions:

1. the heston model function itself, which returns a dictonary with each day as key and the heston model estimated option price for each trade of that specific day as values;
2. the actual/observed option prices function, this function returns a dictonary in similar format as the heston model function.
3. the cost function, this function combines the two dictonaries of the previous functions and returns a list the sum of with all the squared differences for that specific date.

Now comes the problem, I tried to use scipy.optimize.minize() with my cost function, however I feel I have not correctly specified some parts of my three function so far in order to run the minimizer.   Running scipy.optimize.minize() therefore expectly resulted in an error (picture below). It would be very much appreciate it somebody could give me some pointers on possible misspecification in my code.

picture of the dataframe: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kkpl.png

picture of a small sample run: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbSL5.png

picture of error when using scipy.optimize.minimize() https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuLIw.png

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import time
import numpy as np
import QuantLib as ql
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def hestonmodel(kap, the, sig, rho, init_vol):
        dict1 = {}
        for i in range(10): 
                if df_master.option_type[i] == "C":
                        payoff = ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(ql.Option.Call, df_master.strike_price[i])
                else:
                        payoff = ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(ql.Option.Put, df_master.strike_price[i])
        
        day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()
        calender = ql.NullCalendar()
        experation_dates = ql.Date(df_master["maturity_date"][i],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        calculation_dates = ql.Date(df_master["date"][i],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calculation_dates
        exercise = ql.EuropeanExercise(experation_dates)
        option = ql.VanillaOption(payoff, exercise)
    
        spot_price = df_master.index_price[i]
        strike_price = df_master.strike_price[i]
        riskfree_rate = df_master.risk_free_rate[i]
        dividend = 0
        variance = init_vol**2
        initial_value = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(spot_price))

        # Setting up flat risk free curves
        discount_curve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(calculation_dates, riskfree_rate,day_count))
        dividend_yield = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(calculation_dates, dividend, day_count))

        heston_process = ql.HestonProcess(discount_curve,dividend_yield, initial_value,variance,kap,the,sig,rho)
    
        # Inputs used for the engine are model, Tolerance level, maximum evaluations
        engine = ql.AnalyticHestonEngine(ql.HestonModel(heston_process),0.001,1000)
        option.setPricingEngine(engine)
        
        if i != 0: 
                if df_master.day_index[i] == df_master.day_index[i-1]: 
                        dict1[df_master.day_index[i]].append(option.NPV())
                else:
                        dict1[df_master.day_index[i]] = []
                        dict1[df_master.day_index[i]].append(option.NPV())
        else:
                dict1[df_master.day_index[i]] = []
                dict1[df_master.day_index[i]].append(option.NPV())
            
        return dict1

def actualpricefunction():
        dict2 = {}
        for i in range(10):
                if i != 0: 
                        if df_master.day_index[i] == df_master.day_index[i-1]: 
                                dict2[df_master.day_index[i]].append(df_master.price[i])
                         else:
                                dict2[df_master.day_index[i]] = []
                                dict2[df_master.day_index[i]].append(df_master.price[i])
                else:
                        dict2[df_master.day_index[i]] = []
                        dict2[df_master.day_index[i]].append(df_master.price[i])
        return dict2

def costfunction(kap, the, sig, rho, init_vol):
        dict1 = hestonmodel(kap, the, sig, rho, init_vol)
        dict2 = actualpricefunction()
        list1 = []
        for i in dict1.keys():
                list_temp1 = []
                list_temp2 = []
                d1 = dict1[i]
                d2 = dict2[i]
                        for k in range(len(d1)):
                                result = pow((d1[k]-d2[k]),2)
                                list_temp1.append(result)
                list_temp2 = sum(list_temp1)
                list1.append(list_temp2)
    
        return list1
```

The way I tried to run the scipy.optimize.minimize():

```
init_guess = (0.03,1,0.05,-0.6,0.03)
opt = si.optimize.minimize(costfunction(kap = 0.03,the = 1,sig = 0.05,rho=-0.6,init_vol=0.03), init_guess,method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
```